# Prove that the Schmidt number of a state is equal to the rank of the reduced density matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation, quantum-information

> Suppose $|\psi\rangle$ is a pure state of
>   a composite system with components $A$ and $B.$
>
> Prove that the Schmidt number of $|\psi\rangle$ is equal to the rank of the reduced
>   density matrix $\rho_A \equiv \operatorname{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|).$

(Note that the rank of a Hermitian
operator is equal to the dimension of its support.)

I understand that the Schmidt number is the number of non-zero Schmidt coefficients, but I don't know how to generally find that and then proceed with the proof from there.

How do I find the Schmidt number generally?  What is a support?

Answer (score 2):

If the Schmidt number is $r$, then $\lvert\psi\rangle$ can, in some basis, be written as
$$\lvert\psi\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^r \lambda_k \lvert k\rangle\otimes\lvert k\rangle, \,\,\lambda_k\in\mathbb R.$$

It follows that
$$\lvert\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi\rvert=\sum_{jk}^r\lambda_j\lambda_k \lvert j\rangle\!\langle k\rvert\otimes \lvert j\rangle\!\langle k\rvert,$$
and finally
$$\rho_A\equiv\operatorname{tr}_B(\lvert\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi\rvert) = \sum_{i=1}^r (1\otimes\langle i\rvert)\,\,\lvert\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi\rvert\,\,(1\otimes\lvert i\rangle)
= \sum_{j=1}^r \lambda_j^2 \lvert j\rangle\!\langle j\rvert.$$
This means that $\rho_A$ has exactly $r$ nonvanishing eigenvalues, and thus its rank is $r$.

Comment: In this case maybe not obvious, but it is necessarily that $\lambda_k \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @YOUSEFY $\lambda_k$ are always real, they are the singular values of the associated matrix

Comment: Ohh! I think this is because $\psi$ has two qubits and each qubit is associated with a complex amplitude number and the product of two complex numbers is a real number.

Comment: @YOUSEFY no, it's because $\lambda_k$ are singular values, which are always real (and positive). This is true for any bipartite system